# System.in.read() или всё же Scanner?

Tags: java, scanner

Заметил во многих книгах используется: `System.in.read()` - это получить что-то с клавиатуры.
Почему там допустим не используется класс `Scanner`? Потому что `System.in.read()` это быстрее, нежели чем создавать экземпляр класса `Scanner` и далее создавать вот такую конструкцию:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = scanner.nextLine();
```

или же

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = scanner.nextInt();
```

Поискал на Stackoverflow и не нашел отличия System.in.read и класса Scanner.

Comment: Ещё и такой ввод с клавиатуры бывает:                                                                                      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Comment: https://javadevblog.com/klass-scanner-v-java-opisanie-i-primer-ispol-zovaniya.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Разница есть, и притом, существенная. `System.in.read()` может считать только **1** символ в виде `char`.
В то же время, `Scanner` - это универсальная штука, позволяющая считывать в том формате, что надо.
Если требуется считать по символам, то не следует заморачиваться, а использовать `System.in.read()`. В остальных случаях - это, в частности и файлы, используем `Scanner`.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что искусство подачи учебной информации включает умение рассказывать только о том, что относится к теме, без привлечения дополнительных сущностей. Если тема относится к основам считывания данных из потока ввода, то объяснять это через использование токенизатора - это усложнение и отвлечение.

Comment: токенизатора? Это что?

Comment: эээ, вы о чем??

Comment: @ПетровИван `Scanner` - это токенизатор, считывающий ввод, анализирующий его, разбивающий на токены, приводящий их типы, учитывающий локаль, системы счисления и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @michael_best о том, что не стоит объяснять детям почему небо голубое через квантовые эффекты рэлеевского рассеяния и физиологию глаза, неспособного в должной мере различать фиолетовый.

Comment: Как видно из моей репутации, я не сильно "старше" @ПетровИван и мне самому не было известно ничего о токенизаторе до вашего ответа. Я пытался объяснить, чтобы было понятно, а вы, как мне кажется, объясняете через кванты